# Xamarin: Error executing task ConvertResourcesCases: Path is invalid

Tags: android, macos, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am struggling getting my .Droid to be built on my Mac on Xamarin (workds on iOS) as I get the following error message:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: Error: Error executing task ConvertResourcesCases: Path is invalid
Parameter name: path (Kjøleskapet.Droid)
```

I have tried several methods posted on stackoverflow, including deleting the bin and obj folder, rebuilding and cleaning. The Android emulator is working, so that's not the problem.

It worked two days ago, so I'm puzzled to why it doesn't work anymore. I have checked the path and it's all there.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I am using Xamarin-forms

Comment: On a first glance I would say that it due to the ø character. I think it is hard to rule out that that is the cause, but I would avoid using these kind of special characters in your naming as much as possible.

Comment: It worked earlier with this character and has done so many times before. I don't think that is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by starting a new project with a different name. Just copy over the necessary classes/code and change the names accordingly to the new project. My original project and some classes where named 'Kjøleskapet', I changed all to 'Kjoleskapet' and it now works.

I don't know if it was due to the 'ø' character, but it works now nevertheless with the switch to 'o'.